# Problema diagonal de una matriz en C

Tags: c

Teniendo una matriz de 2x2 el promedio de la diagonal es correcto, pero luego ya sea una matriz de 3x3 (en este caso la diagonal tiene 3 números) o una de 4x4 (en este caso tiene 4 números) el promedio siempre da 1 numero de mas a promediar.

Ejemplo:

```
1  2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9
```

La diagonal principal es:

```
1
5   
9
```

La suma de la diagonal principal es: 15 esto es correcto.

El promedio de la variable diagonal es: 3.75 pero aquí el promedio es el resultado de 15/4 no el de 15/ 3(ya que la diagonal tiene 3 números).

Les dejo el código, muchas gracias:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int suma = 0;
    double promedio;
    int i, j, n;
    double aux;
    printf("Ingrese  el valor para una matriz: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int matriz[n][n], cf, cc;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas: ");
    scanf("%d", &cf);
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas: ");
    scanf("%d", &cc);
    for (i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
            printf("Ingrese un valor [%d][%d]: \n ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //imprimir matriz
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //punto A mostar diagonal principal
    printf("La diagonal principal es: ");
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cf; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                printf("%d \t\n", matriz[i][j]);

        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < cf; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
             aux = (i + j);
        }
    }
    printf("La suma de la diagonal principal es:  %d ",suma);

    promedio = suma / aux;

    printf("\n");

    printf("El promedio de la variable diagonal es: %g ",promedio);

}
```

Comment: ¿[tag:c] o [tag:c++]? La respuesta es muy diferente según si es uno u otro.

Comment: Solamente C, ahi borro la etiqueta de c++

Comment: Lástima, me gusta más [tag:c++].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en memoria automática (aquella que no se pide con `malloc`) deben definirse con una constante como tamaño, en tu caso usas la **variable** `n`, lo cuál es incorrecto:

```
int i, j, n;
//        ^ <--- Variable 'n'
double aux;
printf("Ingrese  el valor para una matriz: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
//           ^ <--- Leer valor, en tiempo de ejecución
int matriz[n][n], cf, cc;
//         ^  ^ <--- Incorrecto!!!!
```

Si necesitas definir el tamaño de tu matriz en tiempo de ejecución, necesitarás usar `malloc`:

```
int **matriz, cf, cc;
printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas: ");
scanf("%d", &cf);
matriz = (int**)malloc(cf * sizeof(int*));
//                     ^^ <--- Pedir memoria para 'cf' filas
printf("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas: ");
scanf("%d", &cc);
for (i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
    matriz[i] = (int*)malloc(cc * sizeof(int));
//                           ^^ <--- Pedir memoria para 'cc' columnas
    for (j = 0; j < cc; j++) {
        printf("Ingrese un valor [%d][%d]: \n ", i, j);
        scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
    }
}
```

No olvides liberar la memoria al final:

```
    for (i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
        free(matriz[i])
//      ^^^^ <--- Liberamos cada fila
    }
    free(matriz);
//  ^^^^ <--- Liberamos la matriz
```

> El promedio de la variable diagonal es: 3.75 pero aquí el promedio es el resultado de 15/4 no el de 15/3 (ya que la diagonal tiene 3 números).

No entiendo por qué motivo usas un complicado método para obtener la cantidad de números de la diagonal:

```
for ( i = 0; i < cf; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < cf; j++) {
        if (i == j)
            suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
         aux = (i + j);
    }
}
```

Si ya sabes que tu matriz es cuadrada en cuyo caso el número será el que leíste sobre `n`. Además de que el valor que das a `aux` está mal, es la suma de `i` y `j` que en cada vuelta de cada bucle `j` se sobrescribe con lo que al final resultará en la suma de el último valor de la última vuelta de ambos bucles, que es *2 + 2 = 4*;

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hablando matemáticamente, dado que solamente se puede calcular la diagonal de una matriz cuadrada, puedes pedir un solo parámetro `n` que sea la cantidad tanto de filas como de columnas.

Luego, puedes utilizar directamente `n` para calcular el promedio, ya que una matriz `N x N` tendrá `N` elementos en su diagonal.

Considerando aquello, acá tienes el ejemplo funcional:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int suma = 0;
    double promedio;
    int i, j, n;
    double aux;
    printf("Ingrese  el valor para una matriz: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int matriz[n][n];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("Ingrese un valor [%d][%d]: \n ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // Imprimir matriz
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    // Punto A: Mostrar diagonal principal
    printf("La diagonal principal es: ");
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                printf("%d \t\n", matriz[i][j]);

        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == j)
                suma = suma + matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("La suma de la diagonal principal es:  %d ",suma);

    promedio = suma / n;

    printf("\n");

    printf("El promedio de la variable diagonal es: %g ",promedio);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Gustavo!!!